# Export a group in Figma to PNG at specific size?

Tags: figma

I have a group in Figma that is 1200 x 1200 pixels. I need to export it as a PNG at the following sizes: 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128.

Can I do this without having to resize the group? It's annoying to have to create multiple sizes and there's a border radius set in pixels which doenst scale correctly.

UPDATE: I Looked under export settings but I don't see the option I need there:

[image]

Comment: The information you need is documented [on this Figma help page](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040028114-Guide-to-exports-in-Figma).  See the section under **Add Export Settings**.

Comment: @BillyKerr The only option I have there is for "Contents Only". Ive updated my question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select the group
2. In the Export panel, click the + icon to add an export option

Then proceed as per the screenshot below, repeat step 2 for as many sizes as required.

Note: "w" means width in pixels, or you can use "h" for height in pixels.

[image]

Comment: your "Note" was useful for me. thanks